# iOS: Send number from a TextField, and display it in an alert

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

How could I get a number from a `UITextField`, then put it in a `UIAlertView`?

**Header file**:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *age;
```

**Methods file**:

```
- (IBAction)createStory:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mad Libs Story"

                                                message: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"First name is %@,  favorite place is %@, verb is %@, age is %@, sliderLabel number is %@, petsLabel is %@ and chooseAnimal is %ld", self.firstName.text, self.favoritePlace.text, self.verb.text, self.age.text, self.sliderLabel.text, self.petsLabel.text, (long)self.chooseAnimal.selectedSegmentIndex]
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Explain you question briefly. Cant understand your problem

Comment: what does it is showing now...?

Comment: @Aly I was trying to get the number in the textField to display in a message that I included in an alert. Since it's a number I managed to call through 'self.age.text' and it worked, but I'm wondering how to pass it through as an actual integer within my alert message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mad Libs Story" message:txtField.text delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand of your question, it seems that you would like to take the number that is inside of a `UITextField`, then use that number in a `UIAlertView`. To do that, you could use:

```
NSString *textViewString = age.text; //convert the text of the TextField to a String
```

then, you could put it in your alert view, say in the message, using:

```
- (IBAction)createStory:(id)sender {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mad Libs Story"

                                            message: textViewString
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}
```

Yet, if you're trying to get the literal number (in an `int`), then you could use:

```
int value = [age intValue];
```

to get the number in an int form. You may want to use a `try-catch` statement, to make sure that the NSString can be converted to an int:

```
@try {
   int value = [age intValue];
   //try the code above
}
@catch (NSException *e) {
    NSLog(@"Caught Exception: %@", e); 
    NSLog(@"%@ it not an integer", age);
    //if there is an NSException, log it and do the above
}
@finally {
    NSLog(@"Your number is %f", value);
    [self createStory]; //create the alert
    //if no NSException was caught, execute the above code
}
```

So, lets say the `UITextField` contained `3`, then, it would convert 3 to a string, then to an integer, and it would create the alert view

If it contained `apple`, then, it would catch a `NumberFormatException`, and it would log that it caught an exception, then log `apple is not an integer`, and the alert view would not be created.

Comment: Thanks for the different ways of approaching this problem. I looks like calling 'self.age.text' in the message worked. I created the textfield as an IBOutlet. Where would I put the 'int value = [age intValue];'? Also, where would I put the try-catch code you included?

Comment: @user3255585 you should use the `try-catch` code when your trying to get the int value. You could put the `try-catch` code anywhere you want if you would like to get the integer value of a string.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this a year ago when I was just learning how to code. Looking back now the answer is to be able to grab the data from the uitextfield, in this case, you would use

`self.age.text`

and assign it to whatever variable you would like or include it in the message parameter of the alert object.